# RestTemplate with PEM Certificate and Private Key

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, spring-security, resttemplate

I'm facing an issue connecting to HTTPS server from SpringBoot RestTemplate. The server team provided me with pem certificate (.pem) and private key (.key). I need to configure my spring service to connect over https with the cert and key I have.

What I have done is:

**1- combined the .pem file and .key file in one .pem file using and confirmed I have -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- and -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- in the combined pem:**

```
cat server-cert.pem server-private-key.key > combined-cert-and-key.pem
```

**2- created JKS keystore and trust store and added the cert to it :**

```
keytool -genkeypair -alias dev -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -dname "CN=Preview,OU=B,O=Company,L=City,S=ON,C=CA" -keypass PASSWROD -keystore dev.jks -storepass PASSWROD -validity 3650
keytool -importcert -keystore dev.jks -alias dev1-public-cert -file combined-cert-and-key.pem -storepass PASSWROD -noprompt
```

**3- Exported my JKS as base64 (as I need to that so I can load the file from my config server by rebuilding the JKS)**

```
openssl base64 -in dev.jks -out dev.txt
```

**4- Rest Controller:**

```
    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate rest;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> searchCreditCard(@RequestHeader(value = "Authorization", required = true) String authorization,
        @RequestBody Object bod) {

    String firstDataUrl = String.format("%s", "https://SERVER-DOMAIN/search");
    HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();
    header.set("Content-Type", "application/json");
    HttpEntity<Object> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(bod, header);

    Object response = rest.postForEntity(firstDataUrl, httpEntity, Object.class);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

**5- Aplication.java:**

```
@Value("${tls.keystore.value}")
private String keyStoreValue; // the base64 of my keystore created from #3

@Value("${tls.keystore.password}")
private String keyStorePass;

@Value("${tls.truststore.value}")
private String trustStoreValue; // the base64 of my keystore created from #3

@Value("${tls.truststore.password}")
private String trustStorePass;


@Bean
public RestTemplate template() throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
return new RestTemplate(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(getHttpClient()));
}

private HttpClient getHttpClient() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {
SSLContext sslContext = buildSSLContext(keyStoreValue, keyStorePass, trustStoreValue, trustStorePass);
SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslConnectionSocketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);
return HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(sslConnectionSocketFactory).build();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private static SSLContext buildSSLContext(String keyStoreValue, String keyStorePass, String trustStoreValue,
    String trustStorePass) {
KeyStore keyStore = loadJksKeyStore(keyStoreValue, keyStorePass);
KeyStore trustStore = loadJksKeyStore(trustStoreValue, trustStorePass);

return buildSSLContext(keyStore, trustStore, keyStorePass.toCharArray());
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private static SSLContext buildSSLContext(KeyStore keyStore, KeyStore trustStore, char[] keyPassword) {
try {
    return SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(trustStore, TrustSelfSignedStrategy.INSTANCE)
        .loadKeyMaterial(keyStore, keyPassword).build();
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyManagementException | KeyStoreException | UnrecoverableKeyException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Cloud not setup SSLContext", e);
}
}

private static KeyStore loadJksKeyStore(String based64Value, String password) {
byte[] jksFile = Base64.getMimeDecoder().decode(based64Value);

return loadJksKeyStore(new ByteArrayInputStream(jksFile), password);
}

private static KeyStore loadJksKeyStore(InputStream inputStream, String password) {
try {
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
    char[] passwordAsCharArray = password == null ? null : password.toCharArray();
    keyStore.load(inputStream, passwordAsCharArray);
    return keyStore;
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | CertificateException | KeyStoreException | IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Unable to load JKS KeyStore", e);
}
}
```

However, I'm still getting this error:

```
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target",
```